# Iterate through a JSON array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I just got a jQuery AJAX call to function and now I am having trouble parsing the value that I am returning.  I am working with a mysql database and returning an php `array()` like so to my jQuery AJAX function:  `echo json_encode($reservationArray);`

Now, when I append this to my page in a simple div tag this is the result:

```
[{"reservation_id":"3","available":"0","lock":"0","restaurant":"2","date_made":"2013-12-09 18:39:52","date_of":"2014-01-02 00:00:00","time":"08:30:00","guests":"5","user":"0"},{"reservation_id":"4","available":"0","lock":"0","restaurant":"2","date_made":"2013-12-09 18:40:15","date_of":"2014-01-02 00:00:00","time":"08:00:00","guests":"7","user":"0"}]
```

I believe this is a proper JSON (Please, correct me if I am wrong). I have tried just about every method of accessing the data and cannot.  Below is the approach that I am taking, to construct a new block of code, a bunch of rows - one per reservation (I have shortened the string for this example).

**EDITED:**

```
function my_ajax(rest_id){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'change_restaurant.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {'action': 'get-reservations', 'rest_id': rest_id},
      cache: false,
      success: function(json) {
       $.each(json, function(i, item) {
        if(typeof item == 'object') {
        newhtml += '<div>Restaurant Name :'+item.reservation_id+' Reservation Date: '+item.restaurant+'</div>'
        } 
        else {
          return false;
        }
      })

      $('#reservation-table').append(newhtml);

      },
      error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
        console.log(xhr + "\n" + err);
      }
    });

  }
```

Comment: I don't see a "name" property in the objects in that array. You really need to be looking at your browser's developer console to check for errors.

Comment: @Pointy - I know, I tried to shorten the example I will edit that now.

Comment: @CFitz Can you provide your PHP code as well? If your writing the PHP yourself it means you have an SQL statement that is pulling only from the `reservation` table. You probably need to do a `join` between `reservation` and `restaurant` in order to output the fields you want.

Comment: @maythesource.com This is the information that I want, I just cant get it from a JSON to usable individual variables.

Comment: @CFitz I see you modified the code to use other values.

Comment: Oh, well the problem is that your ajax call is **asynchronous**. You need to put the code that updates the "reservation-table" **inside** the "success" callback.

Comment: @Pointy I'm sorry, I thought that it was?

Comment: @CFitz oh maybe you're right - the indentation is off. You probably should declare "newhtml" somewhere because implicit global variables are a bad thing.

Comment: @Pointy Got IT! I declared newhtml outside of the AJAX call and bingo!  Thank you for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

> I believe this is a proper JSON (Please, correct me if I am wrong).

It seems that the JSON your receiving is not the correct document. 
As Pointy said in the comments, nowhere are there fields "name" or "date".

```
[{
        "reservation_id" : "3",
        "available" : "0",
        "lock" : "0",
        "restaurant" : "2",
        "date_made" : "2013-12-09 18:39:52",
        "date_of" : "2014-01-02 00:00:00",
        "time" : "08:30:00",
        "guests" : "5",
        "user" : "0"
    }, {
        "reservation_id" : "4",
        "available" : "0",
        "lock" : "0",
        "restaurant" : "2",
        "date_made" : "2013-12-09 18:40:15",
        "date_of" : "2014-01-02 00:00:00",
        "time" : "08:00:00",
        "guests" : "7",
        "user" : "0"
    }
]
```

You need to modify your PHP code to perform a query that joins data from `reservations` and `restaurants`.

Answer (score 0):

You also have not instructed jQuery to expect JSON in return. It may be parsing as string. Note the `dataType` option.

```
function my_ajax(rest_id){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'change_restaurant.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {'action': 'get-reservations', 'rest_id': rest_id},
      dataType: "json", // EXPECT JSON
      cache: false,
      success: function(json) {
       $.each(json, function(i, item) {
        if(typeof item == 'object') {
        newhtml += '<div>Restaurant Name :'+item.reservation_id+' Reservation Date: '+item.restaurant+'</div>'
        } 
        else {
          return false;
        }
      })

      $('#reservation-table').append(newhtml);
      ,
      error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
        console.log(xhr + "\n" + err);
      }
    });

  }
```

Comment: jQuery is pretty good at deducing this, though, so I _very_ much doubt it's parsing the data as a string. However, this is probably still good advice.

Comment: Yes, but jQuery needs a MIME type header in order to decide. Given the trouble with the jQuery, I wonder if the PHP includes such a header. `The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response`

Comment: That's true enough. :)